# Can an extension pack set the configuration options of one of the included extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created an extension pack for VSCode. I would like my extension pack to set some configuration options of the included extensions. Can it be done writing some magic in the package.json file of my extension pack?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesconfiguration explains how an extension can create its own configuration using package.json

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1396 seems to be a related vscode issue but I could not say if it allows the changing of the options using package.json.

I have read the package.json files of some vscode extension packs and I have not found any example of what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use [configurationDefaults](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configurationDefaults).

For example, the following configuration from [this extension pack](https://github.com/farlee2121/ionide-and-vscode-solution-explorer/blob/8aa773502624ac781581a46163eb1fcf8d6aee7c/package.json)

```json
"contributes": {
    "configurationDefaults": {
      "FSharp.enableTreeView": false // this is an Ionide setting
    }
  },
  "categories": [
    "Extension Packs"
  ],
  "extensionPack": [ 
    "Ionide.Ionide-fsharp",
    "fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer"
  ]
```

Answer (score -1):

i figured out an answer to this:
redefine the configuration setting but with the changed setting.
take a look at [this code](https://github.com/JohnHeikens/SkriptExtensionPack/blob/main/package.json) for example.

Comment: Don't provide a link-only answer, as the link target can disappear at any time (or doesn't work, like in this case). Always copy the relevant parts in your answer.